# How to implement rust-cpython as_object() and into_object()?

Tags: python, rust

I am trying to implement the trait `PythonObject` for a custom type.

```
impl PythonObject for PyTerm {
    #[inline]
    fn as_object(&self) -> &PyObject {
        //???
    }

    #[inline]
    fn into_object(self) -> PyObject {
        //???
    }

    #[inline]
    unsafe fn unchecked_downcast_from(o: PyObject) -> PyTerm {
        std::mem::transmute(o)
    }

    #[inline]
    unsafe fn unchecked_downcast_borrow_from(o: &PyObject) -> &PyTerm {
        std::mem::transmute(o)
    }
}
```

PyTerm is defined as a custom struct:

```
struct PyTerm {
    // not important fields
}
```

Comment: What's the definition of `PyTerm`, first of all?

Comment: I've added code for the struct

Comment: Tangentially related, but PyO3 is considered to be a go-to crate for Python interop.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in [cpython::pyobject_newtype!](https://docs.rs/cpython/0.5.2/cpython/macro.pyobject_newtype.html) ([sources](https://github.com/dgrunwald/rust-cpython/blob/d77f80caaa36e323b74d904d9e2e03c2a7643d5a/src/objects/mod.rs#L44)).

It looks like the macros is a blessed way to define `PythonObject`s.

Comment: This didn't work because it complained that the field `0` is not defined. I suspect that they only used it for something internal. I've migrated to using PyO3, because it seems to work there https://pyo3.rs/v0.2.7/class.html and because it seems to be more usable and up-to-date.